# Multiple AJAX Callbacks and Creating a List

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm sure this is a common question but I have an input field and a button. Whenever the button is pressed an ajax call is performed returning a string. I understand that if you attach it to a div in the original file, that div will erase any strings or numbers in it and replace with the returned string. What would be the most efficient way to allow for every single callback to be displayed on the screen real time? I attempted it but it appears that dynamically changing the javascript variable that assigns which div tag the ajax callback inserts into does not work. Does anyone know either what is wrong with this code or a more efficient way to write this code, i.e. with php, etc.

```
<div id="part1">

<input type="text" id="text"/>

<input type="button" value="button" id="button"/>

</div>

<div id="hidden" class="2"></div>
<div id="part2"></div>
<div id="part3"></div>
<div id="part4"></div>
<div id="part5"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" >

$('#button').click(function () {

    var text = $('#text').val();    

$.post('ajaxskeleton.php', {
                red: text                   
        }, function(){
        var number = $('#hidden').attr("class");
        $('#part' + number).html(text);
        var number = number+1;                      
        var class_name = $('#hidden').attr('class')
        $('#hidden').removeClass(class_name);       
        $('#hidden').addClass(number);
            $('#text').val('');
    });


});


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of erasing its contents with `.html()`, you could [append](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) the new results to an existing `div` . For *example*, suppose you want to append the results to a `div` with id `results`:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var text = $('#text').val();    
    $.post('ajaxskeleton.php', { red: text }, function() {
        $("<li>" + text + "</li>").appendTo($("#results"));
    });
});​
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KGjuD/)**.

Comment: Thanks it works. Since you posted first correctly I'm giving the check to you.

Comment: A JS Fiddle demo was also supplied, definitely the better answer. No complaints here.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like the following would work.

```
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" id="text"/>

  <input type="button" value="button" id="button"/>
</div>
<ol id="responses"></ol>
$("#button").click(function() {
  $.post('ajaxskeleton.php', {red:text}, function(data) {
    $("#responses").append("<li>" + data + "</li>");
  });
});
```

This just builds up an ordered list with the responses that come back from the Ajax calls, which I think is what your aiming to do.